# Code is being skipped over

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.Runnable;
import java.lang.InterruptedException;

public class Phone implements ActionListener {
        String action = "";
        int callCount = 0;
        int cn = 0;
        boolean calling = false;

        JFrame frame;
        JPanel textPanel;
        JPanel buttonPanel;
        JTextField text;
        JTextArea input;

        JButton one = new JButton("1");
        JButton two = new JButton("2");
        JButton three = new JButton("3");
        JButton four = new JButton("4");
        JButton five = new JButton("5");
        JButton six = new JButton("6");
        JButton seven = new JButton("7");
        JButton eight = new JButton("8");
        JButton nine = new JButton("9");
        JButton zero = new JButton("0");
        JButton star = new JButton("*");
        JButton hash = new JButton("#");
        JButton erase = new JButton("Erase");
        JButton call = new JButton("Call");
        JButton back = new JButton("<=");

    public Phone() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Phone");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(250, 400);

        input = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        textPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel.add(input);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 3));

        frame.add(textPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        buttonPanel.add(one);
        one.addActionListener(this);
        one.setActionCommand("1");

        buttonPanel.add(two);
        two.addActionListener(this);
        two.setActionCommand("2");

        buttonPanel.add(three);
        three.addActionListener(this);
        three.setActionCommand("3");

        buttonPanel.add(four);
        four.addActionListener(this);
        four.setActionCommand("4");

        buttonPanel.add(five);
        five.addActionListener(this);
        five.setActionCommand("5");

        buttonPanel.add(six);
        six.addActionListener(this);
        six.setActionCommand("6");

        buttonPanel.add(seven);
        seven.addActionListener(this);
        seven.setActionCommand("7");

        buttonPanel.add(eight);
        eight.addActionListener(this);
        eight.setActionCommand("8");

        buttonPanel.add(nine);
        nine.addActionListener(this);
        nine.setActionCommand("9");

        buttonPanel.add(star);
        star.addActionListener(this);
        star.setActionCommand("*");

        buttonPanel.add(zero);
        zero.addActionListener(this);
        zero.setActionCommand("0");

        buttonPanel.add(hash);
        hash.addActionListener(this);
        hash.setActionCommand("#");

        buttonPanel.add(erase);
        erase.addActionListener(this);
        erase.setActionCommand("Erase");

        buttonPanel.add(call);
        call.addActionListener(this);
        call.setActionCommand("Call");

        buttonPanel.add(back);
        back.addActionListener(this);
        back.setActionCommand("Back");

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == one || e.getSource() == two || e.getSource() == three 
                || e.getSource() == four || e.getSource() == five
                || e.getSource() == six || e.getSource() == seven
                || e.getSource() == eight || e.getSource() == nine
                || e.getSource() == zero){
            action = input.getText();
            action += e.getActionCommand();
            action = addDash(action);
            input.setText(action);
            System.out.println(""+e.getActionCommand());
        }
        if(e.getSource() == erase){
            action = input.getText();
            action = erase(action);
            input.setText(action);
            System.out.println(""+e.getActionCommand());
        }
        if(e.getSource() == back){
            action = input.getText();
            action = remove(action);
            input.setText(action);
            System.out.println(""+e.getActionCommand());
        }
        if(e.getSource() == call){
            if(!calling){
                String temp = input.getText();
                action = called(temp);
                input.setText(temp + "\n" + action);
                System.out.println(""+e.getActionCommand());
                calling = true;
            } else{
                calling = false;
                String temp = input.getText();
                input.setText(temp + "\n" + "Hanging Up...");
                r.run();
              }
        }
        if(e.getSource() == star){
            action = input.getText();
            action = erase(action);
            input.setText("YOU BAST*&#!");
            System.out.println(""+e.getActionCommand());
        }
        if(e.getSource() == hash){
            action = input.getText();
            action = erase(action);
            input.setText("OMG YOU KILLED KENNY!");
            System.out.println(""+e.getActionCommand());
        }
    }

    public String called(String s){
        if(s.length() == 8){
            return s = String.format("Calling %s%s%s", s.substring(0, 3),
                    s.substring(3, 8), s.substring(8, s.length()));
        }
        if(s.length() == 13){
            return s = String.format("Calling %s%s%s", s.substring(0, 3),
                    s.substring(3, 8), s.substring(8, 13));
        }
        if(s.length() == 0){
            return s;
        }
        return s = "Ill formed number";
    }

    public String addDash(String s){
        if(s.length() == 4){
            return s = String.format("%s-%s", s.substring(0, 3),
                    s.substring(3, s.length()));
        }
        if(s.length() == 9){
            return s = String.format("%s%s-%s", s.substring(0, 3),
                    s.substring(3, 8), s.substring(8, s.length()));
        }
        if(s.length() > 12){
            return s = String.format("%s%s%s", s.substring(0, 3),
                    s.substring(3, 8), s.substring(8, 13));
        }
        return s;
    }

    public String remove(String s){
        return s = String.format("%s", s.substring(0, s.length() -1));
    }

    public String erase(String s){
        return s = String.format("%s", s.substring(0, 0));
    }

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                action = input.getText();
                action = erase(action);
                input.setText(action);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("Thread Interrupted" + e);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I need the three lines of code, above the thread, to execute before the thread sleeps for 2 seconds. This way as the phone is "hanging up" it is displayed on the GUI text area, then the sleep occurs, simulating a hang up.

I don't understand why this is not happening at run-time even though the variable calling is set to false; the two lines following it are not executed.

The code I am referring to is:

```
else{
            calling = false;//executes
            String temp = input.getText();//does not execute
            input.setText(temp + "\n" + "Hanging Up...");//does not execute
            r.run();
          }
```

This code is inside the if statement for the call button of my actionPerformed method.

Comment: I seem to be missing where you actually start the thread or use `r` at all.

Comment: Where do you use `r`?

Comment: r.run() is executed inside the if statement for the call button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java `Runnable`!=`Thread`. In your code you call `run()` on runnable once but you never created thread. You will need to execute something like

```
new Thread(r).start();
```

somewhere.
So I am not sure what 3 lines of code you are talking about but thread is never even created.

Ok. Lets say that you don't create any new thread at all and can just directly execute code from inside `run()` method. In that case, `Thread.sleep(2000)` will just lock UI for 2 seconds.

Comment: Exactly, I need UI to lock for 2 seconds. However, I need the code before it to execute FIRST. While it is locked it should display "Hanging up..."

Comment: I meant that you will block UI (not refreshing or doing anything) for 2 seconds. Generally, if you want to accomplish something like showing Progress while doing something in the background (actually hanging up) you want to use some kind of SwingWorker pattern. I think they were added do JDK long time ago but I am quite rusty on Swing :(. Or lets say, you really just want to block UI from proceeding while hanging up. In this case you want your sleep after you start the thread. Assuming that run() is doing hanging up. Move sleep() after r.run() and use new Thread(r).start() as described.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are executing your `Runnable` makes it run on the current thread, not on a new thread. To run it on a new thread use it like this:

```
new Thread(r).start();
```